# Restore This Revision button is not Enable to Restore the Content

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

Hello I am working with WordPress and I am working on **How to Undo Changes in WordPress with Post Revision**. When I am click on the **Revisions: Browse**

option from the Publish

[image]

I got a **Restore This Revision button** but it is **disabled**. I don't know to 
how enable it because I want the undo some content.

[image]

In above image, button is disabled. What is the  reason? Because I read some

tutorial and their **Restore This Revision button** is not disabled.

Comment: Is this your post? Do you have permissions to edit posts?

Comment: yes it is my post yes i have a permission  to edit the post

Answer (score 2):

In WordPress, somewhat unintuitively, the last revision shown is the current state of the post.

Meaning that in order to revert the last update, you should choose the revision second to last and click "Restore The Revision". The changes currently displayed on the comparison screen will not be reverted, only the changes which took place afterwards.

Hence, in the last displayed revision, the button will always be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Try making another change to the post, new revision will be created. 
The "Restore This Revision" button will start working for the post next to the latest (i.e. the one you have displayed on the screenshots).